# Vuforia-iOS- How to create/add a image target from a UIImage dynamically

Tags: ios, objective-c, vuforia

Is it possible to create a `Trackable` object which uses a `UIImage` or `binary image` data as a source.
If that is possible I can easily load the trackable object to my data set.
But I am not able to find any method for this.
I found this piece of code in user defined targets example, but the `TrackableSource` objects only captures camera frames and I could not find any method which takes image as parameter and returns the object.

`// Add new trackable source`

```
lastCreated = dataSetUserDef->createTrackable(refFreeFrame->getNewTrackableSource());
```

Please suggest something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, in Vuforia it is not possible what you want to achieve.

https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/creating-ar-trackables/target-image-not-xml-and-dat